# Python looping (skip some part)

Tags: python, loops

```
while y != 100:
            dice = random.randint(1,6)
            print('Roll '+str(dice)+' ... '+str(y)+' + '+str(dice)+' is '+str(y+dice))
            z = y
            y = y + dice
            if y > 100:
                    print('Roll '+str(dice)+' ... '+str(z)+' + '+str(dice)+' is over 100. Therefore it remains at '+str(z)+'\n')
                    y = z
                    input('Press <Enter> to roll again...\n')
```

the output of above code is:

(

Press  to roll again...

Roll 5 ... 98 + 5 is 103

Roll 5 ... 98 + 5 is over 100. Therefore it remains at 98

Press  to roll again...)

**How can I skip the 'Roll 5 ... 98 + 5 is 103' part giving just**:

(

Press  to roll again...

Roll 5 ... 98 + 5 is over 100. Therefore it remains at 98

Press  to roll again...)???

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: The output of the code above is: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at `elif`

Comment: this is just an extraction from my whole code, im doin snake and ladder game

Comment: @Lexonss that doesn't explain what you mean by: *How can I skip the 'Roll 5 ... 98 + 5 is 103' part* though ?

Comment: what im trying to ask is how to stop looping on the while loop "print('Roll '+str(dice)+' ... '+str(y)+' + '+str(dice)+' is '+str(y+dice)) = Roll 5 ... 98 + 5 is 103" and just continue the looping in the if loop

Comment: Why not use an `if` before the part of the code that you want to be copied under certain conditions only, as suggested in asnwers below?

Comment: improved my code to be most memory effecient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for `y > 100` *before* printing. Then, if `y` is greater than 100 print the "greater then 100" message and don't print the other message. Ahhhh, it's easier to explain with code:

```
while y != 100:
    dice = random.randint(1,6)
    z = y
    y = y + dice
    if y > 100:
        print('Roll '+str(dice)+' ... '+str(z)+' + '+str(dice)+' is over 100. Therefore it remains at '+str(z)+'\n')
        y = z
        input('Press <Enter> to roll again...\n')
    else:
        print('Roll '+str(dice)+' ... '+str(y)+' + '+str(dice)+' is '+str(y+dice))
```

You can see that I have moved the print statement that includes the actual total into an `else` statement that is executed when `y` <= 100.

I have not checked the rest of your logic.

Comment: Thanks ^^, i solved my problem, i can see that my structures is wrong through your ans XD

Comment: ...yet you have accepted another answer. Nevertheless, glad to have helped you

Comment: Sorry, reputation not enough  hehe

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited code:

```
#import time
y=0
while True:
    #time.sleep(1.0) #Wait 1 second before rolling dice to prevent rolling too fast
    dice = random.randint(1,6); y = y + dice
    if y < 100: print('You rolled '+str(dice)+' ... '+str(y-dice)+' + '+str(dice)+' is '+str(y))
    if y > 100: print('Roll '+str(dice)+' ... '+str(y-dice)+' + '+str(dice)+' is over 100. Therefore it remains at '+str(z)+'\n'); y = y-dice
    try: a = input('Press <Enter> to roll again...\n')
    except: a=''
```

1. You cant have `elif` without an if statement
2. You have to have a variable call `input('Press <Enter> to roll again...\n')` as its value for it to be carried out
3. `a = input('Press <Enter> to roll again...\n')` needs to be carried out no matter what, and not put in the if statement, and it only expects a blank line so it needs to catch the error raised when a blank line is called

Comment: I think OP is using Python 3, in which case the value obtained by `input()` is not evaluated. This is equivalent to `raw_input()` in Python 2.

Comment: not very understand the 'try' and 'except' (im newbie), but still, thanks ^^

Comment: try executes code, and if it doesnt work, instead of displaying the error it undoes the code and executes the code under except instead

Comment: i think i started to understand what you saying, == i still need lot more of practice